# Compare 2nd columns of two csv files

Tags: awk

I need to compare two files on 2<sup>nd</sup> column and generate result as output.csv using `awk`.

file1.csv

```
5, 0,
5, 1,
5, 1,
4, 1,
4, 1,
4, 1,
```

file2.csv

```
5, 0,
5, 1,
5, 1,
4, 0,
4, 2,
4, 3,
```

output.csv

```
5, 0,
5, 1,
5, 1,
4, D,
4, D,
4, D,
```

Comment: You still haven't described the mechanism for translating the input to the output.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the two files have the same number of rows and that the rows in the two files corresponds to each other in a pairwise fashion:

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk -F', *' -vOFS="," '$2 != $4 { $2 = "D" } { print $1, $2 }'
5,0
5,1
5,1
4,D
4,D
4,D
```

The `paste` command will put the two files side by side like so:

```
5, 0,   5, 0,
5, 1,   5, 1,
5, 1,   5, 1,
4, 1,   4, 0,
4, 1,   4, 2,
4, 1,   4, 3,
```

The `awk` code will then read this as data delimited by commas (followed by any number of spaces), and will, for the cases that the second column is not equal to the fourth column, set the second column to the character `D`. The code then prints out the first two column (the second possibly modified) with a comma as delimiter.